# asp file upload control custom text

Tags: javascript, asp.net, file-upload

So I want to use a `<asp:FileUpload>` control to "upload" a picture.

I dont really upload the picture, I just want to get it's `inputstream` so I can change it to a byte array and place it in the database.

However when I add a `<asp:FileUpload>` it comes with a static button and text field. Thou I like the textfield, I want to change the text of the button because my site is full english and the button's text changes depending on.. well something with the language of the browser or OS.

So I searched on google for a while and fould some info about making a html control
`<input type='button' style='visibility: hidden'>` and make another button which activates the  file button by using javascript.

So here's the problem,  when I add `runat=server` to the hidden file button I can't "find" it anymore using the `document.getElementById` javascript function and thus can not get the inputstream or the file.

What i'm asking is if there isn't a simple way to change the text of a `<asp:FileUpload>` so I can still use that control. If not, could you please show me a way how I can get the hidden file button to work with code behind and get it's inputstream?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at blog post [Styling an input type="file"](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html) by Peter-Paul Koch. You may try Ajax [AsyncFileUpload](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AsyncFileUpload/AsyncFileUpload.aspx) control or use uploadify [jQuery plug-ins](http://www.uploadify.com/demos/) too.

Comment: Is the button text of the ajax asyncfileupload control editable or should I hide it and use javascript with a normal button to trigger it?

Comment: Downvoted for failing to answer my question, but you corrected it with the update

Comment: Might be me, but style an input doesn't do anything at IE and firefox, and adds another line with the new controls in chrome. So either it's outdated or just plain not working.